# Looping through a list in C#

Tags: c#

Say I have a list which has 5 values.

```
List<Item> Test
Test[0] 
{Item.category,Item.Number,Item.Format,Item.Order} etc
```

My requirement is that I have to write some HTML code based on the values inside this list.

The way it should be written is that the same Item.Category values should be written together meaning if there are 5 values for `item.category` and 3 of them are same and 2 other are different then the 3 items should be combined meaning the `item.category` will be say the header and the other values like number ,format etc will be the content inside the header.

It should display something like:

```
<h1>Item.category(the 3 same categories should appear here just one)</h1>
{
  all other elements * 3 times

  }
```

If I have made it  difficult to read and understand please let me know.

Comment: what have you tried?  as it stands you've just asked us to do your work for you.

Comment: Could you please provide some real code instead of pseudocode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to understand, but I'm guessing you want to show items based on category with each item appearing under its appropriate category and each category showing only once.

You could try something like this:

```
<% foreach(var g in Test.GroupBy(i => i.category)) { %>
    <h1><%= g.Key %></h1>
    <ul>
    <% foreach(var i in g) { %>
        <li><%= String.Format("Number: {0}, Format: {1}, Order: {2}",
                              i.Number,
                              i.Format,
                              i.Order) %></li>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First sort the list on the category:

```
Test.Sort((x, y) => x.Category.CompareTo(y.Category));
```

When you loop through the items, keep track of the current category, and write out a header if it changes:

```
string category = null;
foreach (Item item in Test) {
  if (category != item.Category) {
    category == item.Category;
    %><h1><%: item.Category %></h1><%
  }
  // output item here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick proposal:

Iterate through the *List< Item > Test* and copy item per item in a new *List< Item > newTest*: with newTest.Add(item);

but first, before .Add(); :

1. look in newTest-List if the item already exists. If yes, don't copy, if no, copy!
2. result: the newTest-List will contain only distinct (no double) entries
3. iterate through the newTest-List and create on the basis of the newTest-List your html elements! (for or foreach)